# How to display one selected record using DetailView?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, detailsview

I have a form in ASP.Net Visual Studio that asks for particular details. After the user inputs their details into the database, I then want to be able to view their records and edit it in a different webform.

How can I view that one **selected** row of records in my form instead of viewing the entire database table?

I thought of using DetailView, however it still shows all the records in the database (just only one at a time).

Then I thought of using sessions but I don't know how about doing this?

Could I possible create a text box to input the persons username (primary key) and then that will open their details?

Update: What I don't want is the DetailView to have other details viewed as well. Meaning I don't want the records of other people on the DetailView as well. I just want the one record of that person, no one else's.

Comment: I really don't understand what do you want to achieve. You write that you want to view "one selected row" and then you write it actually shows you "one at a time". (=so where's the problem?) I think DetailsView is what you want. Did you have a look at some examples / tutorials? http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/detailsview.aspx

Comment: @rocky What I am saying is I want to view one row of records after a user enter's those details. What I don't want is the DetailView to have OTHER details viewed as well. So the records of other people. I just want the one record of that person, no one else's. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

After saving to db, redirect to a new page posting the primary key data using suitable session management techniques & load the details with detailsview

Comment: Sorry for being a pain, but how would I go about doing this?